# How to add directory or make directory to current path and use file

Tags: python, path

I want to make a directory on current path and add an excel file in that path and use that excel file  in script....please help
currently I am doing

```
my_excel_file = Path(sys.argv[2])
if not my_excel_file.is_file():
    print ("Excel File not exist")
    logging.error("Excel File not exist")
    exit(-2)
```

but i want to add directory `'/tmp/old excel/n.xlsx'` in current path and use n.xlsx file

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to create a directory and a file within it using code? Your provided code just reads a file path from runtime arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create a directory and file if does not exist. You can also write to that file :

```
import os

filename = "tmp/old excel/n.xlsx"
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
       os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))

with open(filename, "w") as f:
   f.write("content")
```

Comment: we can use os.path.exists in linux??

Comment: yeah you can use in linux

Comment: i need to run that script on server...no problem right?

Comment: first you have to test it and make sure works in your project without any probs, then you can move forward.